# How to measure interaction between variables (mutations)?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, python, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have a large dataset of germline genetic mutations from a population of 1,000 individuals both affected and non-affected. I've already looked into individual mutations that are enriched in the affected population. Now I want to determine if the presence of two mutations in the same individual is more predictive of disease than having either one individually. Meaning does having both mutation A and B increase probability of being affected significantly more than having just A or just B. I want to identify a list of candidate pairings that show the greatest degree of interaction or predictive value.

The problem seems like something straight forward, but I haven't been able to find any literature dealing with this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In a linear model, this can be done with an *interaction* term.

Comment: Do you have any references I can look at? I'm not quite sure if I know what that means

Comment: You question is posed a little ambiguously, are you merely trying to find which variables to keep in a model because they influence the outcome? Do you think there may be interactions between the variables, such that two or more variables interact to improve predictions more than just including them on their own? As for finding pairs of variables, that's not really done.

Comment: As for interactions, this is a standard topic in linear models, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)

Comment: I have a set over 200 million mutations. Since no mutation was significantly enriched in the affected population, I wanted to test if there is a pair of mutations that are enriched. P(Sick| A ∩ B) > P(Sick| A) and P(Sick| A ∩ B) > P(Sick| B)

Comment: I don't really see a way to do that, unless you build model A, model B and model A+B and then check if model A+B is significantly better then either A or B. And you would have to do this for every pair.

Comment: @user2974951 That could be turned into an answer, if you feel like expanding a little.

Answer (score 1):

There is no model that will perform this as far as I know. The only option I see, if you really wanted to test pairs, is to build 3 models, one with A, one with B, and one with A and B. After this you check whether the last model performs better than the other ones. And you would have to perform this for every possible pair. If you have 200 million mutations (variables) this would result in a stupid amount of models and results.

You have to think of something else to do this, this is not really feasible.